# What is correct to use 'thinked' or 'thought'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, american-english

What is the correct word 'thinked' or 'thought' in the below sentence?

1. You would have thinked about me for few seconds.
2. You would have thought about me for few seconds.

If 'thinked' and 'thought' mean the same then both the sentences will be true right.
Please let me know if I am wrong.

The second sentence is not obvious to pronounce to me.

For me, 'thought' seems to be just 'thought' but not 'taking the decision based on my performance'

Comment: The past participle of "think" is "thought".   Have you read any English textbooks that say "thinked" is grammatical?  If so, then toss them in the trash, as they are unreliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy one. The correct word is **thought**.

There is no such word as "thinked".

If you are having trouble pronouncing "*thought*", it rhymes with "*bought*" (the past tense of "buy").

Comment: "Thought" is the past participle conjugation of "think", period.  It's one of the many irregular English verbs.  Whether or not the overall sentence is grammatical, "have thinked" is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Andrew I didn't say it was idiomatic.?

Comment: I'm saying that the question could have been answered with a dictionary or an English primer.  I can't upvote your answer because A) it's unnecessary, as the question should be closed, and B) you fail to mention the basic underlying grammar.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not begging for your upvote. If you think the question should have been closed then by all means comment on or take action on the question; I don't think it is helpful for you to criticise an answer based on the merits of the question. Also they won't find "thinked" in a dictionary, because the word does not exist. Nor can I comment on the underlying grammar, basic or otherwise, of a word that does not exist.